# EWS and meetings, how to save a meeting with SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone

Tags: java, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to save a meeting (not appointment) but everytime I use the SendToNone setting, nothing shows up on the calendar.  All the other options will make the meeting show up.  I'm guessing this turns the Appointment object into an appointment and appointments aren't showing, but that is not what I want.  I want to save it as a meeting, have a few attendees, and NOT send an invite.  How do I do that?

```
           Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);
           appointment.getRequiredAttendees().add(hostEmail);
           appointment.setSubject(subject);
           appointment.setStart(startDateTZO);
           appointment.setEnd(endDateTZO);
           appointment.getResources().add(roomEmail);
           appointment.setLocation(roomEmail);
           appointment.getOptionalAttendees().add(hostEmail);
           appointment.save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```

Answer (score 0):

Who's mailbox are you expecting it to appear in ? the way you code is written it should appear in the Mailbox of the security credential your running it under. I would suggest you use the FolderId Class and the Mailbox overload to specify the folder you want this saved in eg

```
FolderId CalendartoSaveTo = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, "MailboxToSaveTo@domain.com");
appointment.save(CalendartoSaveTo ,SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```

Comment: I expected it to show up on the rooms calendar for roomEmail, all the other options do that as well.  As well as when I save the attendees.

Comment: It wont show up in the Room mailbox unless you send an Invitation this is the way the automated booking acceptance works in Exchange.

Comment: Thanks for the info!